# Not able to create functions through Azure portal, only VS Code or VS

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an interesting scenario I'd like to see if others have experienced. I wanted to create an Azure Functions app in the Azure portal to reinforce some learning I did over the weekend from A Cloud Guru tutorial. When I created the function app in the Azure portal, I added it to a Github repo to leverage Github Actions. Once the app was created, I went to create a function in the Azure portal and I wasn't able to. I was given options only for VS Code or "any other IDE".

Just to cancel things out, I deleted everything and recreated exactly as I was taught in the tutorial and I noticed after creation, that I was able to create functions from the Azure portal. The difference between my two efforts was that with the second app, I didn't add the app to a Github repo for Github Actions, and that app was able to create from the Azure portal.

Has anyone experienced this behavior before and is this expected behavior. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you added the app to github? Is it a Webapp or the infrastructure as a code to create the Function app (Terraform, Bicep, Arm template etc)? If you have already deployed an application from Github to the function app, you cannot use the portal to deploy anything as it will go out of sync with the git repo. You either use the portal for all deployments or use an IDE or CI/CD for all deployments.  Could you update the question  with what you added to Github repo?

Comment: I was referring to during the process of creating the function app in Azure. When creating a function app, there is a section that asks if you want to link the app to a Github repo and the creation process will provide a boilerplate Github Actions yaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Agree with @Anupam Chand.

AFAIK, After creating a new function app, you get option to create function in Azure Portal.

[image]

But when you enable the GitHub CI/CD deployment or after deploying function from VS Code or VS, you are not allowed to create Function in Azure portal.  The Option **"Develop in Portal"** is removed and you can only deploy functions using GitHub actions or VS code or VS.

It is suggested in MS Doc to deploy function locally.
For Refence check this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Understood, your post makes perfect sense.

Comment: I am glad, it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The portal option only became visible when I choose Windows instead of Linux when creating the Function App.Otherwise it was only showing VS code or any other CLI to create function.